# How to modify field group markup?

Tags: 7, entities

`field_group.module` defines a function as follows:

```
function field_group_pre_render_accordion_item(&$element, $group, &$form) {
  $element += array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#prefix' => '<h3 class="field-group-format-toggler ' . $group->format_type . ($group->collapsed ? '' : ' field-group-accordion-active') . '"><a href="#">' . check_plain(t($group->label)) . '</a></h3>
    <div class="field-group-format-wrapper ' . $group->classes . '">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    //'#attributes' => array('class' => array($group->format_type)),
  );
  if (!empty($group->description)) {
    $element['#prefix'] .= '<div class="description">' . $group->description . '</div>';
  }
}
```

Which is an instance of `field_group_pre_render_<format-type>`.

What I want to do is change that prefix code from an h3 to a div. But I'm not sure what the appropriate function/hook would be to use.

The [Field Group API](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/field_group/field_group.api.php/7) defines a `hook_field_group_pre_render` function but the $element argument in this function doesn't supply the `#prefix` element - so I'm not sure.

Ideally I could just totally override the function `field_group_pre_render_accordion_item` in my own code...

Comment: Could you please try hook_field_group_pre_render_alter?

Comment: I actually laid out every relevant hook, including that one and the aforementioned hook and `hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter` are the only ones that fire - none of these hooks contain the correct info. There has to be a way to directly override the function, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing `hook_field_group_pre_render_alter()` seems the way to go, it's called just after `field_group_field_group_pre_render()` which calls `field_group_pre_render_accordion_item()` and receives the correct info.

It should be like this:

```
function mymodule_field_group_pre_render_alter(&$element, $group, &$form) {
  if ($group->format_type == 'accordion_item') {
    $element['#prefix'] = '<div class="field-group-format-toggler ' . $group->format_type . ($group->collapsed ? '' : ' field-group-accordion-active') . '"><a href="#">' . check_plain(t($group->label)) . '</a></div><div class="field-group-format-wrapper ' . $group->classes . '">';
    if (!empty($group->description)) {
      $element['#prefix'] .= '<div class="description">' . $group->description . '</div>';
    }
  }
}
```

Remember to implement it in a module, as a hook_*_alter() implemented in a front-end theme may not be discovered while flushing cache via drush or in the back-end theme.